# REST api not working

Tags: php, rest, api, yii

I am new to `php` development. Just for practicing I am creating a rest API following a video tutorial. I have followed each and every step but still unable to get the desired result. Below is the code

**Employee Model**

```
class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
     const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

     /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
     public static function tableName()
     {
       return 'employee';
     }

     /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
     public function rules()
     {
        return [
         [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'required'],
         [['emp_name', 'emp_email', 'emp_sal'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
       ];
     }


     public function scenarios()
     {
         $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
         $scenarios['create'] = ['emp_name','emp_email', 'emp_sal'];
         return $scenarios;       
     }

     /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
     public function attributeLabels()
     {
         return [
             'id' => 'ID',
             'emp_name' => 'Emp Name',
             'emp_email' => 'Emp Email',
             'emp_sal' => 'Emp Sal',
         ];
     }
}
```

Above the `ID` field is `auto-increment`

**Employee Controller**

```
public function actionCreateEmployee()
{


   \Yii::$app->response->format= \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;


    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee-> scenario = Employee::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    $employee->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post();

    if ($employee->validate())
    {
        return array('status'=> true, 'data' => 'Employee Created Sussessfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return array('status'=> false, 'data'=>$employee->getErrors());
    }
    //return array('status'=> true);
}
```

Now when I run the API in `Postman`. I got the following result.

[image]

Though I have entered all the required fields data still it gives me `false status`

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `x-www-form-urlencoded`

The documentation says that the `$_POST`-parameter only gets filled on `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` and yii is probably using this.

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

<sup>[from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)</sup>